# read through 4 csv files in python and printing out the row based from the column id

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi guys I am a noob in python and currently learning, and I was wondering if someone can help me with a problem I am facing. I have four files routes.txt, trips.txt, stop_times.txt, stops.txt, the files look like this (the files have thousands of lines):

```
routes.txt 
"route_id","agency_id","route_short_name","route_long_name","route_desc","route_type","route_url","route_color","route_text_color"
"01","1","1",,,3,,"FFFF7C","000000"
"04","1","4",,,3,,"FFFF7C","000000"
"05","1","5",,,3,,"FFFF7C","000000"
"07","1","7",,,3,,"FFFF7C","000000"

trips.txt
"route_id","service_id","trip_id","trip_headsign","direction_id","block_id","shape_id"
"108","BUSN13-hbf13011-Weekday-02","19417636","Malden Station via Salem St.",1,"F411-75","1080037"
"94","BUSN13-hbf13011-Weekday-02","19417637","Medford Square via West Medford",0,"F94-5","940014"

stop_times.txt
"trip_id","arrival_time","departure_time","stop_id","stop_sequence","stop_headsign","pickup_type","drop_off_type"
"19417636","14:40:00","14:40:00","7412",1,,0,0
"19417636","14:41:00","14:41:00","6283",2,,0,0
"19417636","14:41:00","14:41:00","6284",3,,0,0

stops.txt
stop_id","stop_code","stop_name","stop_desc","stop_lat","stop_lon","zone_id","stop_url","location_type","parent_station"
"place-alfcl","","Alewife Station","","42.395428","-71.142483","","",1,""
"place-alsgr","","Allston St. Station","","42.348701","-71.137955","","",1,""
"place-andrw","","Andrew Station","","42.330154","-71.057655","","",1,""
```

I am trying to print the rows based on the column ID's. For example if we had a route_id = "01".

```
check the ID in the routes.txt file and check if that ID is equal to the route_id in the Trips.txt file.
```

If the match is equal

```
take the trip_id from the trips.txt file and compare it with the trip_id in the stop_times.txt file
```

If that is a match check if the

```
stop_id is equal to the stop_id of the stops_file.txt file then print. Now the stop_id can be a number or a     string
```

What I am trying to print out is to print out something like this, for example:

```
route_id, trip_id, arrival_time, departure_time, stop_name
01,19417636, 14:40:00,14:40:00, Alewife Station
```

MUCH APPRECIATED

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is called a [join operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29), and can be done quite easily using the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging) library:

```
import pandas as pd

routes = pd.read_csv('routes.txt')
trips = pd.read_csv('trips.txt')
stop_times = pd.read_csv('stop_times.txt')
stops = pd.read_csv('stops.txt')
```

You may have to change the [options for read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html) so that it interprets your data correctly (especially the leading zeros on the `route_id`s)

```
#   Please excuse the Dr. Seuss variable names
routes_trips = pd.merge(routes, trips, on=['route_id'])
routes_trips_stop_times = pd.merge(routes_trips, stop_times, on=['trip_id'])
routes_trips_stop_times_names = pd.merge(routes_trips_stop_times, stops, on=['stop_id'])
```

By default pandas performs inner joins, so you will end up with only those rows where there are matching `route_id`s, `trip_id`s and `stop_id`s.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest thing to do in this case is import your data into a database and use SQL joins. You can just use sqlite3, which is very simple to do. Even an in-memory database would work,  depending on how much data there is and how often the script would be run.

Make sure you create indexes for the foreign-key fields, otherwise lookups could be slow.

Also, sqlite3 has the ability to import the data directly from the CSV files. Just create the tables then use the ".import" command (run sqlite3 and type .help or just see the docs).

Shawn